# Find record where flag is set in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an model called 'Item', which has many images. Now an image can be the key image for an item. I would like to find all items, which don't have a key image associated with them.

My initial approach was this:

```
Item.joins(:images).where('images.is_key_image' => nil).group("images.item_id")
```

However, this does not group the is_key_image attribute and thus returns the same item over and over gain, until all images have the is_key_image attribute set.

Answer (score -1):

1)may be you should try to group by items.id? you select table items not images
2)are you sure that is_key_image should be nil? very often boolean fields are created with default value false

Comment: Please use comments in order to interrogate the user, not answers.

Comment: I've tried 1), same or worse result. Yeah, my schema.rb shows that null is allowed and it's also in the db and in the records.